# Linux 3.13 Kernel Fails to Compile

Tags: linux, compilation, compiler-errors, makefile, kernel

After configuring various options inside .conf using

```
$make config
```

I try to compile the entire linux kernel using

```
$make
```

However it throws an error as below:

```
root@localbox:/LinuxKernel/linux-3.13# make
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
***
*** Configuration file ".config" not found!
***
*** Please run some configurator (e.g. "make oldconfig" or
*** "make menuconfig" or "make xconfig").
***
make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
make[1]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `relocs'.
make: *** No rule to make target `include/config/auto.conf', needed by `include/config/kernel.release'.  Stop.
root@localbox:/LinuxKernel/linux-3.13#
```

I tried to search for .conf by using:

```
$find -name ".conf"
```

However it turns up no results. But since make config worked I assume .config must exist somewhere.

Please advise me on how to overcome this annoying problem. I am doing this for the first time and I am not sure if there are any dependencies that have to be installed before trying to compile the kernel. Your feedbacks are highly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Linux admin and may be better on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Chris, I think it goes beyond linux administration. I am having issues compiling the kernel from source code. I believe only linux kernel developers can address this issue convincingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must have been some error with `make config`, e.g. disk full or you aborted it with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>. The `.config` file (not `.conf`) is right in the main directory.

The error message says it already

```
*** Please run some configurator (e.g. "make oldconfig" or
*** "make menuconfig" or "make xconfig").
```

There are several textbased (config, oldconfig, menuconfig) and graphical (xconfig, gconfig) configuration programs. You might want to pick a graphical one and run it, e.g.

```
make gconfig
```

These graphical configurators also help to avoid all the hundreds of irrelevant questions. When you're done selecting the needed options, don't forget to save the `.config` file and try again compiling the kernel and modules.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I have issues with gconfig, its asking for GTK+ 2.0 libraries. I am presently working on it.

Comment: You can also try menuconfig. This is a text-based configurator similar to gconfig. There you can also pick individual options, without going through all the other questions. It needs only ncurses, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks I was able to use make menuconfig for generation of .config file after which make works. I guess my gap in understanding was that .config file has to be generated using the aforementioned utilities before make can be invoked to compile the kernel, please correct me if I am wrong on this - doing it for the first time.

Comment: yep menuconfig turned out to be the easiest method for me. Highly recommend it.